# You have a nil object when you didn't expect it

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I’m interested in the topic of Rails security and using [Security on Rails](http://pragprog.com/titles/fr_secure/security-on-rails). I'm on Implementing RBAC /page 142/ and i cannot get past the error in the subject. 
Here is the code:

```
module RoleBasedControllerAuthorization

  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(AuthorizationClassMethods)
  end

  def authorization_filter
    user = User.find(:first, 
      :conditions => ["id = ?", session[:user_id]])

    action_name = request.parameters[:action].to_sym
    action_roles = self.class.access_list[action_name]

    if action_roles.nil?
      logger.error "You must provide a roles declaration\
        or add skip_before_filter :authorization_filter to\
        the beginning of #{self}."
      redirect_to :controller => 'root', :action => 'index'
      return false
    elsif action_roles.include? user.role.name.to_sym
      return true
    else
      logger.info "#{user.user_name} (role: #{user.role.name}) attempted to access\
        #{self.class}##{action_name} without the proper permissions."
      flash[:notice] = "Not authorized!"
      redirect_to :controller => 'root', :action => 'index'
      return false
    end
  end      
end    

module AuthorizationClassMethods
  def self.extended(base)
    class << base
      @access_list = {}
      attr_reader :access_list 
    end
  end

  def roles(*roles)
    @roles = roles 
  end

  def method_added(method)
    logger.debug "#{caller[0].inspect}"
    logger.debug "#{method.inspect}"
    @access_list[method] = @roles  
  end
end
```

And @access_list[method] = @roles line throwing following exception:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of ActiveRecord::Base.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]=):
  app/security/role_based_controller_authorization.rb:66:in `method_added'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:5:in `<class:ApplicationController>'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  app/controllers/home_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

I'm using Rails 3.0.3 and Ruby 1.9.2. I'm storing session in database. In finally thank you for every advise.

Comment: That book is probably written for Rails 2.3 and Ruby 1.8. There have been very significant changes in both with the latest versions. I'd try running it on that combo and see if there are still issues. If you use RVM you can switch rails and ruby versions really quick.

Comment: Ok. I'm using RVM. But i need it on Rails 3 and Ruby 1.9.2. Please help me?

Comment: When you add exception backtrace, try to mark at least some line numbers, because it's hard to know, about what lines exception is.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you can't access `@access_list` in `method_added`. I would try

```
class << base
  attr_accessor :access_list 
  @access_list = {}
end
```

Might not solve your particular problem, but otherwise you won't be able to call `@access_list[method] = @roles` if your access_list attribute is read-only.

Comment: `@access_list` would normally be in scope inside the instance so the accessor wouldn't be needed. `attr_accessor` creates getter/setter methods that allow code outside the instance to get at the value of the instance variable, without the developer having to explicitly write them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the problem, but this looks suspicious:

```
class << base
  @access_list = {}
  attr_reader :access_list 
end
```

Shouldn't `@access_list` be a class variable `@@access_list`?

Answer (score 0):

Your defining `@access_list` as a instance variable of the class but your accessing it in as a instance_variable of **an instance** of the class. The following should probably work:

```
module AuthorizationClassMethods
  def access_list
    @access_list ||={}
  end

  def method_added(method)
    logger.debug "#{caller[0].inspect}"
    logger.debug "#{method.inspect}"
    access_list[method] = @roles  
  end
end
```

If you need Auhorization you might want to check out Cancan by Ryan Bates

https://github.com/ryanb/cancan